# How to write an integration test for a loop?

Tags: ruby, rspec, rspec3

I am having difficulty writing integration (no stubbing) tests for the following scenario: a process (rake task) that runs in a loop, emitting some values. Below is an approximation of the use case.

The test will succeed if I control-C it, but I would like it to catch the success condition and stop.

Anyone has some good suggestions? (stubbing/mocking are not good suggestions). I guess may be there is a way to instruct RSpec to stop a process after a matcher returns success?

```
describe 'rake reactor' do
  it 'eventually returns 0.3' do
    expect { Rake::Task['reactor'].execute }.to output(/^0\.3.*/).to_stdout
  end
end

class Reactor
  def initialize
    @stop = false
  end

  def call
    loop do
      break if stop?

      sleep random_interval
      yield random_interval
    end
  end

  def stop
    @stop = true
  end

  def stop?
    @stop == true
  end

  def random_interval
    rand(0.1..0.4)
  end
end

desc 'Start reactor'
task reactor: :environment do
  reactor = Reactor.new
  trap(:INT) do
    reactor.stop
  end
  reactor.call { |m| p m }
end
```

Answer (score 0):

A naïve way to handle it is to start a new thread and send INT from there after some predefined timeout:

```
  before do
    Thread.new do
      sleep 0.5
      Process.kill('INT', Process.pid)
    end
  end
```